# Template function C++, that take param U and return T

Tags: c++, qt, templates

I am in trouble with Templates, I want to get the content of a file and store it in a String. I'm working with Qt on a generic function which will handle char *, QString and string.

I have a template, which i call with:

```
std::string test = openStyle("style.css");
```

I want to get in *test* the value **styleToAdd**, which is the content of my file **style.css**:

**EDIT:** change const T&openstyle to const T, thanks to Stadium.

```
template<typename T>
const T openStyle(const T &type)
{
    QFile File(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + type);
    File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString styleToAdd = QLatin1String(File.readAll());

    return (styleToAdd);
}
```

But compilation say:

```
invalid initialisation of reference type "const char (&)[14]" from expression "QString"
```

I think it is because in the template, the return value is the same as the parameter and not my **test** variable, but is there a way to be able to return another type (in generic way)

so we can do things like that with the template:

```
std::string test = openStyle("style.css");
char * test = openStyle("style.css");
QString test = openStyle("style.css");
const char * test = openStyle("style.css");
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a template function when: it's parameter is a filename, which is always a string; and you always want it to return a string. There's no need for a template function, here. As the saying goes: "the more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain".

Comment: If you can use C++14, give auto return type deduction a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to automatically determine the return type of a function in the way you tried it.

If you want a template function as you described, the syntax would be like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
const T &openStyle(const U &type)
```

but you would need to call it like this:

```
std::string test = openStyle<std::string,const char[]>("style.css");
```

which is probably not what you want. Besides this you would have to find a way to convert your `QString styleToAdd` to any type `T` - so the problem is not solved but just moved to the return type.

Since the filename is always a string, you can simply choose one here and always return a `QString` and define your function like this:

```
const QString &openStyle(const std::string &type) 
//choose if you like std::string, QString or char[] here.
```

While you can not overload the cast operator outside of QString, you could overload the stream operator globally for the needed types:

```
 operator<< (std::string& left,const QString& right){left = right.toStdString();}
 operator<< (char*, const QString&); //similar conversions here
 operator<< (QString&, const std::string&); //and here
```

using the provided functions `QString::toStdString()` and `std::string::c_str()` and then write:

```
std::string test << openStyle("style.css");
char * test << openStyle("style.css");
QString test << openStyle("style.css");
const char * test << openStyle("style.css");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can compile with C++14, with his automatic return type deduction with `-std=c++1y`:

```
template<typename T>
auto T openStyle(const T &type)
{
    QFile File(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + type);
    File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString styleToAdd = QLatin1String(File.readAll());

    return (styleToAdd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need templates for this. If `type` is anything that is not a string or cannot be implicitly converted into one, your code will fail.

I see the examples you want to get from this and all I can tell you is that

- `QString` has the `toStdString()`, `toUtf8()` etc. functions which return the `std::string` equivalent of your `QString` object
- `std::string` can be converted to a C-string using `c_str()` function.

In addition you can also convert a `QString` to a C-string using a `QByteArray` to store the result from `QString::toLatin1()` and then call `QByteArray::data()` and assign it to a `const char *`. This is a little bit over the top omho but it's another way of doing things.

You can create small functions that do this for you if you don't want to go through all the steps and calls every time you want to convert `QString` to one of the two standard C/C++ string representations.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are using QT, you probably could consider using only the QString class and eventually call QString's methods when you want to convert it to a const char* or std::string object. You don't really need template for this. You could use something like that:

```
QString openStyle(const QString &type) { ... }
```

Also there's one really nasty bug into your code: you're trying to return a const reference to a local variable, which is wrong and will lead to an undefined behavior (very likely you'll get a core dump).
As you can see, I have changed your return type from const T& to T.